# C++ non-zero default value for numeric types - reinvention?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, types, default-value

I have in mind a construct like this:

```
template <typename T, T defaultValue>
struct Numeric
{
    Numeric(T t=defaultValue) : value(t) { }
    T value;
    T operator=()(T t);
    operator T();
};
```

I might use it like this:

```
std::vector<Numeric<bool, true> > nothingButTheTruth;
```

My question is simple:  Is this a good approach and if so, does something like this exist in a standard library or Boost?

Comment: It's a bit hard to see how you would ever end up in situations where it wouldn't be straight-forward to specify the initializer. For example, in a vector you would say `v.resize(10, true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern I see more commonly is to parameterize the container, not the type.

There are a lot of downsides to doing it your way:

- While you provide assignment and conversion, you can't actually bind
  a `bool&` to a `Numeric<bool, true>`.
- A `vector<bool>` and a `vector<Numeric<bool, true> >` are unrelated
  types.

This gets pretty painful pretty quickly. I wouldn't do it, but perhaps you have a strong use case.

Comment: Yes, true.  But my type won't always be contained like this so maybe a bad example on my part.

Comment: Funny that you use `vector<bool>` as an example, as `vector<bool>` infamously [isn't actually a `vector` of `bool`](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm).

Comment: @Spire I only used `bool` because the OP did. But I admit I never knew that `vector<bool>` was so significantly specialized (but I also never used `vector<bool>`). Another reason to believe that new languages can picked up quickly but their standard libraries, that's a completely different kettle of fish.